# Angular formControl fails to load

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm following Angular tutorial on forms here:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

I have this code in 'datasources.component.html':

```
<form [formGroup]="queryForm">
<label>Query:
<input type="text" formControlName="query">
</label>
```

And this in 'datasources.component.ts':

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'sql-editor',
templateUrl: './datasources.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./datasources.component.scss']
})
export class DatasourcesComponent {
queryForm = new FormGroup({
    query: new FormControl(''),
});
```

}

I see its stuck at 'websocket : pending'

Also, my original intent is to make it work for 'textarea'. Is the solution going to work for that too?

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="sql-query" [formControl]="query"></textarea>-
```

I'm using Angular version 7.2:

**EDIT:**
I see this error in console 'Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Comment: do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: thanks I'm new to UI development so didn't know where to look. I see this error in console 'Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Comment: import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the Module that this Component is registered in. Or you'll have to export the `ReactiveFormsModule` from some other module(SharedModule for instance) and then import that module in the module that you have this Component registered in.

Comment: I think it is simply `formControlName` rather than `[formControl]`. I.e `formControlName="query"`, without the input bindings

Comment: Yes, It should be `<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="sql-query" formControlName="query"></textarea>-`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your AppModule

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  // other imports ...
  ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

`formGroup, formControl`, etc are all `directives` that are exposed as a part of the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

If you want to use these `directives` in a Component, you'll have to either import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the Module that this Component is registered in. Or you'll have to export the `ReactiveFormsModule` from some other module(`SharedModule` for instance) and then import that module in the module that you have this Component registered in.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  // other imports ...
  ReactiveFormsModule
 ],
})
export class YourComponentModule { }
```

Also use the formcontrols like shown below:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="sql-query" formControlName="query"></textarea>
```